# Dynamic validation in metro applications

Tags: c#, validation

Im developing an application for the windows store in c#, and wondering whats the best way to dynamically validate data in controls such as Textboxes, Dropdown boxes etc.

At the minute I usually check the validation when a buttons clicked, I would like to be able to notify the user in realtime.

An example of where i would like this to be used in when a user registers with an email address I would like to check the format of the string using a regex command.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use relay command
eg [Relay Command](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d44932d3-ba6a-4ca1-88e0-c34665123a5c/implementation-relaycommand?forum=wpf) and MVVM pattern

Comment: Thanks, this is something i will def look into